# ConditionalWeakTable still holds references that should be GC collected?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm using `ConditionalWeakTable` for the purpose of loosely holding references instead of strongly referencing using a traditional lookup like `Dictionary`. 
However I've tested one case to double-check that capability and looks like it's failed. The following code is based on `Windows Forms` however you can try adjusting it using any framework or platform you want:

***The sample models***:

```
public class SampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Main code***:

```
//at some class level scope
BindingSource _bs;
ConditionalWeakTable<BindingSource, object> _lookup = 
                          new ConditionalWeakTable<BindingSource, object>();

public void Test(){
   _bs = new BindingSource();
   var item = new SampleModel();
   _bs.Add(item);
   _bs.ListChanged += (s,e) => 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed! There is some memory leak");
   };
   _lookup.Add(_bs, new object());
   //here the old instance is not referenced by any variable
   _bs = new BindingSource();
   //try collecting all collectable things
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   //try changing the item's property
   //the old instance of BindingSource if not collected will still 
   //fire the ListChanged event and the handler will show a message box 
   //as you see above.
   item.Name = "some name";
}
```

The testing app is built in Release mode to ensure that the GC works correctly.
And the result is the message box always shows. 
The expected result is no message box shown.
Note that the `Test` method is run just once for each time running the testing app.

Could you please explain something wrong here?

Comment: The mapping of the `ConditionalWeakTable` may get garbage collected if the key is unreachable, but of course, as long as you’re holding a strong reference to the `SampleModel` instance via the `item` variable, that object won’t get garbage collected, whether there is a mapping in `ConditionalWeakTable` or not.

Comment: @Holger I don't understand that point, I think there is not any reference/relationship or link between the `BindingSource` instance (just a container) and the item of `SampleModel`, that item does not have any property pointing to the list. ***unless*** there is some hidden code doing that kind of linking (inside the framework) and I'm not aware of such thing.

Comment: I’m not a C# programmer and don’t know what these classes do, but *obviously*, when the `(s,e) =>  { MessageBox.Show("Failed! There is some memory leak"); }` function gets evaluated upon a change of the `item`, there *must* be a link between them, i.e. a reference from that item to that lambda, either directly or indirectly via the `BindingSource`. The most important point is, regardless of how these three artifacts interact, the existence of the additional `ConditionalWeakTable` does not change it.

Comment: @Holger after some thinking from your comment, looks like you're right. That kind of linking is really hidden under the internal registration to `PropertyChanged` event exposed via `item`. So the `item` will hold reference to the `BindingSource` (as the target of some handler for `PropertyChanged` event).